# (1 Chronicles 3:21) verse "...the sons of Rephaiah, the sons of Arnan, the sons of Obadiah, the sons of Shecaniah...". Unclear?

Tags: hebrew-bible

From my perspective, the (1 Chronicles 3:21) verse is Unclear.
I'm confused as who are the sons referenced when said verse mentions "...the sons of Rephaiah, the sons of Arnan, the sons of Obadiah, the sons of Shecaniah...".
Most of the other verses that describe the lineal descendants are quite clear, however, (1 Chronicles 3:21) verse is Unclear?

> (1 Chronicles 3:19-24) New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 19 The sons of Pedaiah were Zerubbabel and Shimei. And the [a]sons of
>   Zerubbabel were Meshullam and Hananiah, and Shelomith was their
>   sister; 20 and Hashubah, Ohel, Berechiah, Hasadiah and Jushab-hesed,
>   five. **21 The [b]sons of Hananiah were Pelatiah and Jeshaiah, the
>   sons of Rephaiah, the sons of Arnan, the sons of Obadiah, the sons of
>   Shecaniah.** 22 The [c]descendants of Shecaniah were Shemaiah, and the
>   sons of Shemaiah: Hattush, Igal, Bariah, Neariah and Shaphat, six. 23
>   The [d]sons of Neariah were Elioenai, Hizkiah and Azrikam, three. 24
>   The sons of Elioenai were Hodaviah, Eliashib, Pelaiah, Akkub, Johanan,
>   Delaiah and Anani, seven.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a simple explanation that will clear things up for you.  I went to my New Living Translation Study Bible which discusses the genealogy of the Israelites from Jacob to the exile to Babylon.

Chapters 2 to 4 give details of the tribe of Judah
Chapter 3 is about the House of David
Chapters 5 to 7 is about the other tribes of Israel (the tribe of Levi is in chapter 6)

The line from Solomon runs through Josiah, Jehoiachin, Pediah, Zerubbabel, and to Hananiah.  The sons of Hananiah appear to extend over five generations, not one, as explained in the study notes from the NLT:

> At the end of the monarchy of Judah the sequence of kings did not follow the typical pattern of the eldest son succeeding his father.  The sons of Hananiah... Shecaniah are listed in one generation BUT the NLT extends over several generations from Zerubbabel and his son Hananiah.  (Hebrew beney = sons of... x 4 and Hebrew beno = son of... x 1).

Source: New Living Translation explanatory notes on 1 Chronicles chapter 3s